# Azure access token generation from Postman

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, access-token, bearer-token

I wanted to generate Azure token from Postman for API authorization in my project. I am able to generate token using below API request but getting the below error message "**Authorization denied for this request**" while using the generated token in another API request.

**Endpoint#**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/:tenant_id/oauth2/token
```

**Params#**

```
tenant_id:As per id generation by azure.
```

**Body#** (Form-data)

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:As per id generation by azure.
client_secret:As per id generation by azure.
resource:Required URL
```

**Response#**

```
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "foo",
    "ext_expires_in": "foo",
    "expires_on": "foo",
    "not_before": "foo",
    "resource": "foo",
    "access_token":foo
```

Since the above returned token is not accepted, I had passed username and password as well in body of the request but ended up with same results. Also azure did not consider my credentials even they are wrong.

Could you please assist what else I need to send in the response to get valid token id?

Comment: See the updated answer and do exactly I have shown. You will get token definitely. Let me know if you have any more concern

Comment: I applied as per your direction and getting token successfully but problem is generated token is not accepted as valid token when passed in another API for authentication purpose.

Comment: Where are you passing this ? which resource you are trying to access? show the URL

Comment: POST>>>https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<My tenant name>>.microsoft.com/oauth2/token. sending these inbody(Grant type, clientid, client_secret and resource)

Comment: This is token endpoint , after getting token where do you passing it? not this URL

Comment: For example this API I want to access with my token `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`. So what API you are trying to access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Valid format for `client_credentials` authentication flow is like below:

**Azure Portal Credentials For App Id and Tenant Id:**

[image]

**Application Secret from Portal:**

[image]

**Token Endpoint Or URL:**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
```

**Request Param:**

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:b603c7be_Your_App_ID_e6921e61f925
client_secret:Vxf1Sl_Your_App_Secret_2XDSeZ8wL/Yp8ns4sc=
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
```

**PostMan Sample:**

[image]

**Token On Response:**

[image]

**Expose Your Own API:**

When You want to authorize your own API you have add it here. So that your token will contain this permission and this API can be accessed. Refer this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#expose-a-new-scope-through-the-ui)

[image]

For more clarity you could refer [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

Comment: I am still getting the same error ("Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request.") while using the generated access token.

Comment: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token`  like this . Please update your question with screen shot if possible

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding "X-ZUMO-AUTH" header to your request when using the generated token.

```
GET https://<appname>.azurewebsites.net/api/products/1
X-ZUMO-AUTH: <authenticationToken_value>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to